# Rounding on Visualforce

Tags: visualforce

I'm having a little trouble with how Visualforce is rounding my calculation.  The relevant VF code is:

```
<apex:OutputText value="{0, number, 0.00%}">
                             <apex:param value="{!(mapTotalHrs[btd.Budgeted_Program__c]/objTimesheets.Total_Hours_to_be_Paid__c)+ 
                                                (objTimesheets.Non_Work_Payable_Hours__c/objTimesheets.Total_Hours_to_be_Paid__c * (btd.Budgeted__c/objTimesheets.Total_Budgeted_Per__c))}"/>
          </apex:OutputText>
```

If the actual value of the calculation is 20.125%, Visualforce rounds it down to 20.12% where I would expect it rounded up to 20.13%.  Is there a way to force it to round 5's up?  Otherwise my page isn't matching some associated apex code that I have working elsewhere.

Comment: Why dont you calculate this in controller and display this value in `<apex:outputText>`?

Comment: Especially if you have this working somewhere else in your codebase, what happens if the formula changes? You'll have to update the code and all other references, on your pages.. best to only have to change a single location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rounding is (probably) half-even based on e.g. [NumberFormat.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/2c6933c5106b/src/share/classes/java/text/NumberFormat.java). That rounding depends on the preceding digit (1 in your example) and aims to be [fairer than other methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28134938/what-is-half-even-rounding-for).

So a good way to "fix" your problem is to also use that fairer rounding mode in the "associated apex code" so that is consistent with the Visualforce rounding.

If you don't want to do that and if it is difficult to refactor as described in the comments to your question, you can influence the rounding by adding say 0.001 (not sure that is the right value to use...) to the value being presented:

```
<apex:param value="{! 0.001 + (mapTotalHrs...
```

though you would need to test quite a few values to be confident of the results.